# new graph with adding 1 edges and number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, connected-components

In a preparing class for `ACM-Contest`, our Teacher has given us one printed page of a solved problem. On one page its written that, `2` of the following facts are True but she won't say, `why or what`:

> "with adding new 1 edge to a Directed Graph, how many of these may be
>   true about number of strongly connected component of this graph?

```
+) at most 1 unit is increased.

++) at most 1 unit is decreased.

+++) maybe not changed.

++++) maybe decreased by more than 2 units.
```

anyone could expanded it clearly with our teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(+) is false (under a generous interpretation of "increase at most", i.e., implying that there is no decrease) and (++) is false and (++++) is true because if we add the feedback arc from one end of a path to the other, making it a cycle, then we go from n strong components to 1. (+++) is obviously true.

```
Before (4 strong components):
* --> * --> * --> *

After version A (1 strong component):
___________________
|                 |
v                 |
* --> * --> * --> *

After version B (4 strong components):
___________________
|                 |
|                 v
* --> * --> * --> *
```

Comment: I confused about this sentence" because if we add the feedback arc from one end of a path to the other, then we go from n strong components to 1"

Comment: @MinoJende We go from an acyclic path to one big cycle.

Comment: is it possible to make an example for this part of your sentence?

Comment: wow, really nice, thanks. my last question is about +++? I couldn't understand it !

Comment: @MinoJende Added another diagram.

Comment: you are the best clever person i see